# FPS is fixed at a single position only

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

[image]

I am making a VR Game in Unity. But the problem is, after generating the apk and installing it in my phone, when I look through the cardboard my first person character is fixed at a single position only.

When I look at different directions, the fps arm remains at the same position, it doesn't rotate according to the direction I am facing.

I am using Unity Cardboard asset and I am working on Unity 5.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem before, make sure that your model is a child of the Head Component, that way your model will be fixed to the head as it rotates.

[image]

**EDIT**

From the image you supplied in your question, you have the Unity Standard Asset FPS controller. This moves by mouse movement, which of course you cannot do on a phone. Because your arms are a child of the FPS Controller, they will only move if the mouse moves. Therefore you need to make your Arms a child of the Head component, like so:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so seen as though you are using Cardboard, in your scene you should have something called `Cardboard Main`. If you click on the arrow, there will be something called `Cardboard Head`. You need to drag and drop your model onto the Head component.

Comment: @MehrabZaman I have added a picture to my answer to help you understand better :)

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of some of your project by editing your question?

Comment: Is that FPS controller the one included as part of the Unity Standard Assets? If it is, I think that is only controllable with a mouse or a gamepad, which is why the Arms do not appear. You need to detach the Arms and any other body parts and parent them to the Head Component

Comment: yup it is the unity standard asset......arms appears but it doesn't move according to the direction i am looking.......i have parented it.....i have given the screenshot....please have a look

Comment: That image is the same as the one you had before. You need to move your arms to make it a child of the head **instead** of a child of the FPSController

Comment: @MehrabZaman I have edited my answer, hopefully this will help! :)

Comment: i have done it but my fps is moving but camera is not moving

Comment: Then I'd suggest creating a new `Cardboard Camera` and attaching some cubes to the head component. If that works, add some other things until you get what you want. Failing that, come back and ask again! :)